# Does Canonical collect data about how I use Ubuntu?

Tags: security, canonical

Does Canonical collect any user data about me or my habits during my use of Ubuntu? And if so, how can I stop this data collection?

Comment: Define the "who" please before we can answer this.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I am voting to reopen as his comment on the answer provides the needed information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.  If you're browsing the internet, you can be tracked on anything since you're requesting data from external servers, which keep track of that data and when and who from it was requested.

If you're talking about spyware, there are very few spywares out there for Ubuntu, but they're out there.  Linux is "Security through Obscurity"

Comment: I  meant do the company Canonical track my behaviour or collect data about me when I use ubuntu?

Comment: From my experiences, Canonical themselves don't track your behavior or collect your data for their own use, but they do remember what you download from the Software Center so they can give suggestions, but this is TURNED OFF BY DEFAULT.

Comment: In other words, don't worry about it.  Your secrets are safe.

Comment: Thx for your answer. So you menat that Canonical collect data for someone else, lite Amozon or ?? Or to put it this way: is ANYONE tracking my behaviour, collecting data about me when i use Ubuntu? I.e. does ubuntu respect integrity or not?

Comment: I don't think they share with anyone else AT ALL, and I think that anything to provide history is done locally, and not with Canonical.